# Passing Item (entire class) of Parent Control List to Command

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Is there a way to pass a child entire class of parent Collection Control (in my case ListBox) into Command in ViewModel? I can pass any single value, either 'IsChecked', 'AttachmentId', or 'Name'. All three properties are part of 'Attachment' class. 'AttachmentLst' (item source of ListBox contains 'Attachment' elements. I would like to pass entire class into my Command. Below is working code for passing just one property, in this case 'AttachmentId'. How to pass 'Attachment' into the Command?

```html
            <telerik:RadListBox telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Name="lstAttachments" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding AttachmentLst}">
                <telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Command="{Binding ElementName=lstAttachments, Path=DataContext.AttachmentChecked}"  CommandParameter="{Binding AttachmentId}" Content="Test" />
                            <Label Content="{Binding AttachmentId}" FontSize="12"></Label>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Name}" FontSize="12"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadListBox>
```

ViewModel

```html
        public ObservableCollection<Attachment> AttachmentLst
        {
            get { return _attachmentLst; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _attachmentLst, value); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Commands
        public ICommand AttachmentChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return _attachmentChecked ?? (_attachmentChecked = new CommandHandlerWithParam(obj => ExecuteAttachmentChecked(obj), CanExecuteAttachmentChecked()));
            }
        }

        private void ExecuteAttachmentChecked(object obj)
        {

        }

        private bool CanExecuteAttachmentChecked()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use**

```
  CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}},Path=DataContext}"
```

to pass entire item as `CommandParameter`.

> You can also use `templateParent`/ `Self` Binding instead of `Ancestor`
>   Binding. DataContext will be the same for all.